# avconv error: av_interleaved_write_frame

Tags: video, video-encoding, avconv

I use avconv to cut a video and to remove subtitles.
Depending on the length of the output video, I get a success or and error.

The input video has the following information:

```
avconv -i video.mkv
```

> Metadata:
>
> Duration: 00:02:07.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15559 kb/s
>
> ```
> Stream #0.0(eng): Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 720x576 [PAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 15000 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
> Stream #0.1(fre): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s (default)
> Stream #0.2(ger): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 112 kb/s (default)
> Stream #0.3(eng): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
> Stream #0.4(qaa): Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s (default)
> Stream #0.5(fre): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000 (default)
> Stream #0.6(fre): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000 (default)
> Stream #0.7(ger): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000 (default)
> Stream #0.8(ger): Subtitle: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000 (default)
> ```
>
> At least one output file must be specified

For a duration of 40s of video, this works properly:

`avconv -i video.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:02:30 -t 00:00:40 -sn test3.mkv`

For a duration of 2min30s, an error is raised:

`avconv -i video.mkv -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:02:30 -t 00:10:40 -sn test3.mkv`

Output:

> Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 308600 >= 308600
>              av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

Has anyone an idea of the reason of this problem?

Comment: Possibly a bug since fixed in `ffmpeg`? See: http://askubuntu.com/a/493882/49860